# Jest + Selenium: how do I do an operation before and after all tests inside a describe block is run?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jestjs

I am trying to create a simple automated test to detect if the added element contains the text it is supposed to have. The test is run using node.js with `jest` command. I am using Selenium to automate the UI process and Jest to validate the UI's content.

I want to do the following.

- Create variables that are accessible in all `test`s in the `describe` block before running **any** of the test
- Close the Selenium-driven browser after all `tests` in the `describe` block is run

So far, I have this code.

```
const { Builder, By, until } = require('selenium-webdriver')
const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'

describe('addUser', async() => {
    afterAll(async() => {
        await driver.quit()
    }, 15000)

    test('valid name and age should add a new element', async() => {
        const driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build()
        await driver.get(url)
        const nameField = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('name')), 10000)
        const ageField = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('age')), 10000)
        const btnAddUser = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('btnAddUser')), 10000)
        await nameField.click()
        await nameField.sendKeys('Adam')
        await ageField.click()
        await ageField.sendKeys('39')
        await btnAddUser.click()
        const userItem = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('.user-item')), 10000)
        const userItemText = await userItem.getText()
        expect(userItemText).toBe('Adam (39 years old)')
    }, 10000)
})
```

The problems I am facing are the following.

- I have to declare the `driver`, ask the `driver` to open a new page, and finding all the necessary elements every time I run a test. If possible, I would like to do these initialization steps inside a `beforeAll` function (by Jest) and store the variables somehow. Then, I can use `driver`, `nameField`, `ageField`, etc. in every test without having to declare them again. How would I do this while maintaining a clean code?
- I will close the Selenium-driven browser after all tests inside the `addUser` `describe` block are run. So, I added `driver.quit()` inside `afterAll` (Jest) to close the browser. Unfortunately, this doesn't work; the browser doesn't close itself. How can I close the Selenium-operated browser after each `describe` block?

The test is working great, but how can I solve the two problems above?

Comment: `driver` is declared in test scope, it's not available in afterAll. Either use separate drivers for each test, define them in beforeEach and do driver.quit() in afterEach. Or reuse the same driver, define in beforeAll and do driver.quit() in afterAll.

Comment: @EstusFlask I tried defining `driver, nameField, ageField, and btnAddUser` inside `beforeAll`. However, when I tried to access `nameField`, `ageField`, and `btnAddUser` inside `test`, it says that `nameField` is not defined.

Comment: If you *declare* variables inside beforeAll (`let`, etc), they won't be visible inside test. This is specific to JS rather than Jest, you may want to check on variable scopes. You certainly don't need nameField, etc in beforeAll because they are specific to this test, while driver isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`driver` variable is declared in `test` scope and is unavailable in `afterAll`. Even if it were declared in `describe` scope, a teardown would be performed only for the last `driver` because there can be multiple tests but `afterAll` is called after the last one.

Variables that need a teardown can be either redefined for each test:

```
let driver;

beforeEach(async () => {
  driver = ...
});

afterEach(async () => {
  await driver.quit()
});
```

Or reused for all tests:

```
let driver;

beforeAll(async () => {
  driver = ...
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await driver.quit()
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted. I don't know why I couldn't define `let` in the `describe` scope previously; I must have missed something (I've tried what you did before, but I guess I mistyped or misconfigured something).